# Button value also taking while doing check/uncheckall

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i am clicking checkall button, then i am clicked Assign To button, i am getting value is ["on","a","b"], but this not my expected output

> ```
> Expected output
> ```

```
["a","b"]
```

```js
var tableElement = $('table');
tableElement.on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(event) {
  var changed = event.target,
    checkboxes = tableElement
    .find('input[type=checkbox]')
    .not('#select-all');

  if (changed.id === 'select-all') {
    checkboxes.prop('checked', changed.checked)
  } else {
    var allChecked = checkboxes.length === checkboxes.filter(':checked').length
    $('#select-all').prop(
      'checked', allChecked
    );

  }
});

$(document.body).on('click','#assign-comments',function(){
var commentIDs =[];
     $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
            commentIDs.push( $(this).val());
        });
console.log(commentIDs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>monitoring</title>
        
         </head>
        <body>
        <table>
                <tr class="w3-gray" style="width:100%">
                        <th> <input id="select-all"  type="checkbox" name="test[]">checkall</th>
                        <th><span>User name</span></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name ="checklist" value ="a"></td>
                        <td>a@123</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name ="checklist" value ="b"></td>
                        <td>b@123</td>
                </tr>
        </table>


        <button type="button"  id="assign-comments"  >Assign To</button>
        </body>
        </html>
```

anyone please update my code and explain what i am doing wrong ?,**on** value coming from where ? i have tried my level best, but i am not getting the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's coming from the 'check all' checkbox itself, probably related to the value Test[]. Easiest solution would be to do an explicit check for the 'select-all' id if possible to ensure you don't include it.

Happy coding!